# How to config Apache & php run as superuser

Tags: php, apache, unix, freebsd

i try to config apache & php for my project to create web-based for file config management to open vpn in bsd unix, but i can't run as superuser to start or stop service

Answer (score 2):

you can use a script with a [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) to do the actual command.

ie some bash script like this would do it

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/init.d/openvpn $1
```

you shoud `chmod +s yourscript.sh` and use a `system('yourscript.sh start')` in PHP.

**Note:** You have to be really careful with that because it could make big security holes

Comment: but i using mod_suexec (apache server) and FastCGI(php), I don't know how to config and test if its work, can u give any resource about that,:)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sudo access on the machine? That is, can you prefix your start/stop commands with "sudo" to run them as a superuser?

If not, I think you're out of luck. But there's almost no information here to work with.

Comment: yes indeed. I think I misinterpreted his question, actually. Your response was probably what he was looking for.